# Why is the last console.log() output not shown?

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to make a really simple “guess the number” game using JavaScript.

I want it to have a maximum limit of 5 guesses. If you guess, the program tells you in how many tries you got the answer and stop the game if you surpass 5 guesses.

I have just one problem. If you made your 5th guess wrong, it just displays the message *“you used your 5 guesses and the solution was 10”*, and I want to also show your last guess and with the appropriate message (“go higher” / “go lower”).

Can you help me? For the purposes of this question, I changed the number to be guessed with a fixed variable rather than a random one.

```js
var solution = 10;
var n = prompt("Enter a number");
var i = 1;

while ((i < 5) && (n != solution)) {
  console.log(n + " is too " + ((n < solution) ? "small" : "big"));
  n = prompt("Try again");
  i++;
}

if (n == solution) {
  console.log("Good job, the solution was " + n + " you got that in " + i + " tries")
}
else {
  console.log(" You lost, your " + i + " tries have ended")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the line:

```
console.log( n + " is too " + ((n < solution) ? "small" : "big"));
```

inside the last else statement and you should be ok

```js
var solution = 10;
var n = prompt("Enter a number");
var i = 1;

while ((i < 5) && (n != solution)) {
  console.log(n + " is too " + ((n < solution) ? "small" : "big"));
  n = prompt("Try again");
  i++;
}

if (n == solution) {
  console.log("Good job, the solution was " + n + " you got that in " + i + " tries")
}
else {
  console.log( n + " is too " + ((n < solution) ? "small" : "big"));
  console.log(" You lost, your " + i + " tries have ended")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var solution = 10;
var n;
var i = 0; // don't read input here, and set i to 0 not 1


while( ( i < 5 )  &&  ( n != solution)){

    if(i==0){n = prompt ("Enter number");}
    else{n = prompt ("Try again");}
    console.log( n + " is too " + ((n < solution) ? "small" : "big")); // write that AFTER reading input, not BEFORE.
    i++;
}

if ( n == solution ){
    console.log("Good job, the solution was " + n + " you got that in " + i + " tries")
}

else {
   console.log(" You lost, your " + i + " tries have ended")
}
```

Comment: @epascarello added some comments

Comment: this seems to work for the 5 errors in a row and seems more elegant than adding another console.log to my else statement but i tried it and it gives an output of  "10 is too big" and then " Good job , the solution was...... "(even though 10 is the right answer)

Answer (score 0):

I edited your last console.log statement. This produces your desired results, based on what I understood from your question.

```js
var solution = 10;
var n = prompt("Enter a number");
var i = 1;

while ((i < 5) && (n != solution)) {
  console.log(n + " is too " + ((n < solution) ? "small" : "big"));
  n = prompt("Try again");
  i++;
}

if (n == solution) {
  console.log("Good job, the solution was " + n + " you got that in " + i + " tries")
}
else {
  console.log(n + " is too " +((n < solution) ? "small." : "high.") + " You lost. Your 5 tries have ended." )
}
```

Comment: i want the 5th try to go through the  "console.log(n + " is too " + ((n < solution) ? "small" : "big"));" something like this
1 is too small
2 is too small
12 is too big 
11 is too big
9 is to small
You lost, your 5 tries have ended.